# Pushwoosh - native Android - not receiving notifications

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, native, pushwoosh

I went through all steps in documentation. All permisions added to AndroidManifest.xml, GCM enabled for my application ID.
No errors or warnings in console:

`03-09 18:34:50.701 27716-27897/.*****.****** I/Pushwoosh: [RequestManager] | Pushwoosh request:| Url: https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/registerDevice| Payload: {"request":{"device_type":3,"jailbroken":1,"userId":"882480c50abde42e","android_package":".*****.*****","timezone":3600,"v":"3.3.0.607","app_version":"1.0","sounds":[],"device_model":"Samsung SM-G920F","device_name":"Phone","push_token":"fvalCSNQGro:APA91bHb7_phOm9NuBrTsAGg65-LeJy54d4346ujpuAF8j4kVJm2cNIoWf3MOGB2qUjiMzK573Xd1-yfUwr6mf4rnAzjAIm89WvYtZkvReK69q25OZas3mm1iQjh4Raan04Cl66mprEc","os_version":"5.1.1","language":"en","application":"A7FD7-0B3C0","hwid":"882480c50dade42e"}} Response: {"status_code":200,"status_message":"OK","response":null}x
03-09 18:34:50.701 27716-27897/.*****.****** D/Pushwoosh: [RequestManager] registerDevice response success
03-09 18:34:50.701 27716-27716/.*****.****** V/Pushwoosh: [RegistrationPrefs] Setting registered on server status as: true
03-09 18:34:50.711 27716-27716/**.*****.****** W/Pushwoosh: [DeviceRegistrar] Registered for pushes: fvalCSNQGro:APA91bHb7_phOm9NuBrTsAGg65-LeJy54d434453fruAF8j4kVJm2cNIoWf3MOGB2qUjiMzK573Xd1-yfUwr6mf4rnAzjAIm89WvYtZkvReK69q25OZfs3mm1iQjh4Raan04Cl66mprEc`

[I have all of my devices registered successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7Rgy.png)

Do you have any ideas why I dont get any notifications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution!
GCM was unauthorized because of wrong API key. I had to change it to Server Key at console.developers.google.com

Answer (score 0):

What does push status says in the "Push history" page? That's the best place to see what is actually happens with pushes when you send them.

Comment: Are you on WiFi? Sometimes ports required for GCM are closed on the routers. Try to switch to 3G?

Comment: Also tried this. 3G and WiFi - no results.
Everything works just fine with my iOS application.

Comment: Another idea. Do you have Google Play Services updated on a device? Open Google+ to check (it will prompt if the services is out of date).

Comment: Thank you for your ideas.
Unfortunately still nothing... The weirdest thing is that even their sample app from Pushwoosh documentation doesn't work.
I test with 3 or 4 devices.